# AngularJS - Closing bootstrap popover on button click from within the popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

As demonstrated through the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/O1TK12kJT8vnLKPPILc0?p=preview. I want to show a bootstrap popover on click of `Cancel` button. First time when I click the button, it opens up the popover, but after that I have to click the button twice to have the popover open. Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need to implement your own popover directive and don't use the one available here: angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/? It has the option to use a template by url and also to close the way you need it.

Comment: actually it opens at first time, then after every second click... have a try by yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your code is due to the toggle functionality that popover has. So after popover is closed, the first time you click on it, actually it removes the toggle and the second time is already opening the popover.

Solution (based on your plunkr):

Change the controller and directive to the above:

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
 $scope.cancel = function(msg) {
  $scope.msg = msg;
 };
});

app.directive('cancelConfirmation', function($compile, $timeout) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    onCancel: '&'
  },
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      var content = '<div><p>Are you sure you want to cancel?</p><button id="yes" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="no()">No</button>&nbsp;' +
        '<button id="no" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button></div>&nbsp;';

      elem.popover({
        html: true,
        content: $compile(content)(scope),
        placement: 'top'
      });

      elem.on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
        elem.attr('disabled', true);
      });

      scope.yes = function() {
        elem.popover('hide');
        elem.triggerHandler('click');
        elem.attr('disabled', false);
        scope.onCancel()('yes called');
      };

      scope.no = function() {
        elem.popover('hide');
        elem.triggerHandler('click');
        elem.attr('disabled', false);
      };
  }
};
});
```

and on your cancel button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" cancel-confirmation data-on-cancel="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have a workaround:

```
elem.popover({
   html: true,
   content: $compile(content)(scope),
   placement: 'top',
   trigger: 'manual'
});

elem.on('click', function() {
   elem.popover('show');
});
```

This way you have to manually trigger if the popover is shown and to add the click listener on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/86koF02Wga5yGVvhoKrY?p=preview) solution for you.

Steps to get this:

1.remove directive from your script

2.add bootstrap-tpls.js from [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and include it in your page header

3.change script to have application with injected bootstrap and controller to this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.yes = function() {
      console.log('yes called');
    };

    $scope.no = function() {
      console.log('no called');
    };
});
```

4.create a `yes-no.html` template with the following markup:

```
 <div><button id="yes" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="no()">No</button>&nbsp;
 <button id="no" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button></div>&nbsp;
```

5.change your cancel button to

```
 <button popover-trigger="focus" uib-popover-template="'yes-no.html'" popover-title="Some title here?" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
```

Enjoy a much simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks @Diana for the solution. I know that `ui-bootstrap` provides a directive for it. But I am trying to understand what am I missing from my code, if we just use bootstrap's popover? Is it because the the element gets detached from the DOM?

Comment: @AnupVasudeva in your example, you don't have any event related to focus lost of the popover that would close it. This is what is missing.

Comment: I just want the popover to be closed on the `No`/`Yes` button and  not on blur event.

Comment: @AnupVasudeva oh, now I got it. The issue is cased by the fact that the button is working as toggle. So after popover is closed, ahen you click on cancel, it actually untoggles the button and second time only opens the popover again.

Comment: Spot on. You are right. Your solution made my code working. Now if you care to add a new answer below with the suggestion you mentioned me, so that I can mark it. Here's the updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zGliZU9iR4eN2g9iTIdX

Comment: Sure. Will add it now.